# Dapper C#: Split column Type object into TypeID and TypeName

Tags: dapper

I am using dapper and want to split

```
Class EType
{
    int TypeID;
    string TypeName;
}

Class Employee
{
    int id;
    string location;
    EType EmpType;
}
```

Employee Table:

```
ID||Location||TypeID||TypeName
```

During CRUD operations using Dapper, i want conversion of EmpType into respective columns in DB automatically.Tried type handlers and custom maps. But no luck:(.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to use properties, not fields. Then use Dapper's [multi-mapping](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper):

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public EType EType { get; set; }
}

public class EType
{
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class MultimappingTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestSplit()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=foo"))
        {
            var result =
                conn.Query<Employee, EType, Employee>(@"select Id = 1, Location = 'earth', TypeId = 2, TypeName = 'human'",
                    (employee, type) =>
                    {
                        employee.EType = type;
                        return employee;
                    }, splitOn: "TypeId").First();

            Assert.That(result.EType.TypeId == 2);
            Assert.That(result.EType.TypeName == "human");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. Is there anyway to handle insert and update as well? Splitting EType into Typeid and Type name automatically.